# Videogular 2 with HLS (hls.js) on ionic 3 : No video in emulators

Tags: android, ionic3, http-live-streaming, videogular, hls.js

I prepared copy of needed files in assets (hls.min.js and videogular2/fonts) 
I imported hls.min.js and css in index.html

```
<script src="assets/hls.min.js"></script>
<link href="assets/fonts/videogular.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I imported modules in my app.modules.ts :

```
import {VgCoreModule} from 'videogular2/core';
import {VgControlsModule} from 'videogular2/controls';
import {VgOverlayPlayModule} from 'videogular2/overlay-play';
import {VgBufferingModule} from 'videogular2/buffering';
import { VgStreamingModule } from 'videogular2/streaming';
```

Added them to imports section :

```
imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
   VgCoreModule,
   VgControlsModule,
   VgOverlayPlayModule,
   VgBufferingModule,
   VgStreamingModule
 ],
```

and added to home.html :

```
<vg-player>
    <video #myMedia
           [vgHls]="'https://storage.googleapis.com/shaka-demo-assets/angel-one-hls/master.m3u8'"
           id="my-video"
           type="video/mp4"
           controls>
    </video>
</vg-player>
```

It works fine with

```
ionic serve
```

But not working in mobile :
Android emulator : sound, no video
IOS emulator :  crash on polyfill.js

Is there a way to make it work on mobile with hls ?

Comment: Might be due to Content Security Policy  Have a look at this discussion ...

https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media/issues/80

Tell us how you go!

Comment: I will try it for sure. Thanks Tony.

Comment: Did that fix it?